# Automatic calculation of the number and size of the panels used in the assembly

Tags: solidworks

I am experienced in industrial design but not in architecture. Although its main purpose is not architectural design, I am working on a building drawing with solidworks.

[image]

Although such large structures are not drawn in detail (i.e. in parts rather than a single body), rather, on the exterior; I am trying to find (rather, have the program calculate) how many glass, stainless sheet and wood panels will be used and the dimensions of the cut panels.

Because at the end of the design, I want to find out how many of each panel is used. I need to discover the number of uncut 2 square meters panels and how many of the cut 2 square meters panels are there, and also what the new dimensions are.

Let each of the glass, stainless steel sheet and wood panels be assumed to be 2 square meters. Imagine being assembled with an array of copies, each of which follows a path for each floor.

When you look at the picture, you will see that it is used at a variable rate on each floor. Because while one spline cuts the glass and wood with a different path, another spline cuts the stainless steel sheet and wood panels.

Thus, 20 panels of stainless steel, 8 wooden panels and 10 glass panels are used on one floor, while 14 stainless steel, 12 wooden panels and 6 glass panels are used on another floor. Moreover, the panels at the intersections do not have an area of 2 square meters, the spline path has cut the panels in different sizes.

When you divide the building with a spline separating the glass, wood and stainless panels, is there a way to have the program calculate how many panels will be used on each floor and what dimensions the panels at the intersections will be?

I need this automatic quantity and measurement calculation to send the required dimensions and quantities to the suppliers who will produce the panels when the entire exterior is finished.

For example

for the 12th floor;

12 glass panels (two of them this size, the others 2 square meters since it cuts the spline)

6 wooden panels (two of them this size, the others 2 square meters since it cuts splines)

8 stainless panels (two of them are of this size, the others are 2 square meters since they cut splines)

for 15 floors;

8 glass panels (two of them the following size, the others 2 square meters since it cuts the spline)

12 wooden panels (two of them this size, the others 2 square meters since it cuts splines)

6 stainless panels (two of them are the following size, the others are 2 square meters since it cuts splines)
Is there a way/method to do this?